# Main Icon change from ImageList

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

D5pro: I'd like to change the Application Icon in the task bar when my app is running for a while. I have an TImageList with two icons, 0 and 1 and I found this which does not force a compile-time error, but doesn't change the icon on the taskbar.

```
ImageList1.GetIcon(0, Application.Icon);
// Do stuff for ten minutes here
//...
// and to put it back when finished 
ImageList1.GetIcon(1, Application.Icon);
```

I tried an `Application.ProcessMessages` but it made no difference and the original Icon is still showing.

Comment: The code in the question does not compile. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The basic mechanism for changing the icon is correct.  Your problem is that the work you are doing in the main thread is preventing your process from responding to the change of icon appropriately, i.e. to update the display of the icon on the task bar.

One way to deal with this is to place the work in a background thread and modify your application so that it follows the following process:

1. Change icon to "busy" state.
2. Create thread to perform work
3. Change icon back to "ready" state when work is complete

By placing the work in a background thread your main thread remains free to respond to the necessary messages to update the icon in response to the changes made to it.

This implementation demonstrates the principle.  First a very simple thread class that simulates 2 seconds of "work":

```
type
  TWork = class(TThread)
    constructor Create(aOnTerminate: TNotifyEvent); reintroduce;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;


constructor TWork.Create(aOnTerminate: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  OnTerminate := aOnTerminate;
  FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;

  inherited Create(FALSE);
end;

procedure TWork.Execute;
begin
  Sleep(2000);
end;
```

This is a simple "fire and forget" thread.  It will run, perform its work and then destroy itself.  This is setup in the custom constructor which accepts an event handler to be installed as the **OnTerminate** handler for the thread before invoking the inherited constructor to initialise and start the thread.

The **Execute** method of the thread simply waits for 2 seconds before completing.  Exiting the **Execute** method then triggers the **OnTerminate** event.

The application code then simply has to change the icon to the running state and create an instance of this work thread to perform the actual work.  The code to restore the application icon back to the ready state goes in the callback event to be called once the work is done:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    btnDoWork: TButton;
    procedure btnDoWorkClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure OnComplete(Sender: TObject);
  end;


procedure TForm1.btnDoWorkClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImageList1.GetIcon(0, Application.Icon);
  TWork.Create(OnComplete);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnComplete(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImageList1.GetIcon(1, Application.Icon);
end;
```

**NOTE: This is intended to demonstrate the principles involved.  It is not a complete and robust solution.**

By placing the work in a background thread it is possible that other complications will arise that will need to be addressed if the work performed is not entirely self contained.  For example, it may not be appropriate for the thread to free itself when done and synchronisation techniques may be required to ensure thread-safe access to any data shared between the work and other parts of your code and/or to update UI in other ways if required during the work performed by the thread.

But it does demonstrate a solution to your current problem.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the details. You gave me an idea and instead of a Thread I created two procedures as it would be a big job to ensure all would work in a Thread. One changes the icon to red, then launches the long-process procedure and the other is visited at the end of the long-process to turn the icon back to green. Working fine.

Comment: That doesn't really hang together at all, @user. Whether the icon is changed from a procedure or not, before the work is started, or just after it is started, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @David, I had the same thought when I read that but didn't have the time to get into it.  I cannot fathom how the approach user983145 makes any substantive difference to the (easily reproduced) problem.  But they say it works for them, whatever it's doing so what the hey, eh ? :shrug:  :)